# I wrote a code for Renaming files in a directory with Python but getting an error :( any suggestion?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os

filenames = os.listdir(input("Enter the Path to Directory:"))

for filename in filenames:
os.rename(filename, filename.replace(".", " "))
```

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/programming/Source Code/projectsssssss/p_test/rename.py", line 8, in 
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace(".", " "))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'sdcasd.asdwecwe3.acac3.3ca.wca.txt' -> 'sdcasd asdwecwe3 acac3
3ca wca txt'

Comment: Can't find a duplicate at the moment but please do some research before asking. This question comes up at least twice a day. `listdir` returns file names (not full paths) while `rename` expects the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*os.listdir()* will only give you a filename, you have to add a path to it, in order to rename it

```
import os

path = "/www/css/"
filenames = os.listdir(path)

for filename in filenames:
   old_file = os.path.join(path, filename)
   new_file = os.path.join(path, filename.replace(".", " "))
   os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```